# What happens at the other side of the piston?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

In a standard 4 stroke vertical internal combustion engine, Does the downward piston movement compress gas below it? If so, does it affect efficiency?

Answer (score 6):

In a single-cylinder engine, yes, although the crankcase is usually vented. The total change in volume and/or pressure isn't all that great anyway. And any energy absorbed by compressing the air is returned on the next up-stroke.

In multi-cylinder engines, there are pistons moving up when other pistons are moving down, so the change in total crankcase volume is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Not as such, for a start the space in the crank case is quite a large volume compared to the cylinder bore and will in any case usually have a breather system of one sort or another. The most important reason for this is to prevent oil from the crankcase and sump from being forced back past the piston rings into the combustion chamber.

However there is still a certain amount of resistance just from displacing this air, although this may be quite small compared to the resistance from induction fuel/air into the cylinder.

Induction is a small but not insignificant part of overall efficiency.